# file watch, no such file or directory for emacs autosave file

Tags: node.js, file, emacs, gulp, livereload

gulp watches files for livereload,

```
gulp.watch([
    '/templates/**/*.hbs'
], ['build-dev-templates']);
```

but when i edit on emacs, it creates autosave files like `.#index.hbs` and `Gaze` gives this error:

`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'app/client/templates/.#index.hbs'`

How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to move your backup files elsewhere. I use this snippet [from What the .emacs.d!?](http://whattheemacsd.com/init.el-02.html) to put all backup files into `~/.emacs.d/backups`:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `(("." . ,(expand-file-name
                 (concat user-emacs-directory "backups")))))
```

You should be able to use a similar technique for [moving auto-save files](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave#toc1). Something like this should work:

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
          `((".*" ,(expand-file-name
                    (concat user-emacs-directory "auto-save")) t)))
```

Comment: on a second thought # files are not backup files, they are auto-save files how do i get rid of them?

Comment: @facebook, I believe you can use the same technique with `auto-save-file-name-transforms`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: finally that didn't help as well, problem was emacs creates symlinks to lockfiles, `(setq create-lockfiles nil)` fixes, don't know there is an alternative to this.

Comment: i think emacs should be fixed rather than gulp. so this answer is cool.

Comment: Have you tried `(setq make-backup-files nil)` or to type `M`-`x` `auto-save-mode` to completely turn off the file creation ?

Comment: Emacs is doing the correct thing: The lock file must be in the same directory to ensure that it is created atomically(!). Anything else is subject to races between different editor instances.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to exclude the backup files of your watcher with this pattern :

```
gulp.watch([
  '/templates/**/*.hbs',
  '!/templates/**/.#*'
], ['build-dev-templates']);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only thing that worked was to disable the .# file creation with

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

This functionality has been added in Emacs 24.3.